# Importing QField data issue - Photos importing as "{extension}" files instead of "jpg"

Tags: qgis, convert, qfield, jpg, photos

I use QField to record field data points with information and field photos. The layer I use in qfield to collect data has fields to input comments, dates, etc and an assigned photo1 field specifically for photos taken in the field. However, when I import the data from the phone/QField, it imports all my data correctly except for the photos. For some reason, the photos are coming on to my computer and into QGIS as "{extension}" files when I need them to be "jpg" files to open and view them. Is there a way to convert extension to jpg easily? If not then what would cause photos using QField to save as an extension file?